# Short names in Windows paths

Tags: windows

In some batch scripts I see that "C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1" is used to represent the path "C:\Oracle\Middleware". I want to know why this is abbreviated, and in which place the mapping between 'MIDDLE~1' and 'Middleware' is being stored in Windows. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short file names are automatically generated by windows to enable compatibility with old MS-DOS based or 16-bit programs, which expect all file names to be in 8.3 form - that is, 8 symbols for name and 3 for extension. Details on how short names are generated from long names can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976806.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I understood this part. But, if I need to get the full file name from the shortened form, how do I get it ? (In the given example I was able to guess but can't always do that)

Comment: For example, you could use powershell script to get a full path name from short. Run from command line: powershell -Command  "[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath(\"C:\\PROGRA~2\\desktop.ini\");"

Comment: Link to MS support is dead.

Comment: updated dead link

Answer (score 0):

It's microsofts way  of managing long file names.

[read it here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_filename) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142982/en-us)

excerpts:

```
Long filenames (LFN), are Microsoft's way of implementing filenames longer than 
the 8.3 filename, or short-filename, naming scheme used in Microsoft DOS in their
modern FAT and NTFS filesystems. Because these filenames can be longer than an 
8.3 filename, they can be more descriptive. Another advantage of this scheme is 
that it allows longer extensions common on other operating systems (e.g. .jpeg, 
.tiff, .html, and .xhtml) rather than specialized shortened names (e.g. .jpg, 
.tif, .htm, .xht). The first Microsoft Windows operating system to implement 
long filenames on FAT was Windows NT 3.5 in 1994.

The long filename system allows a maximum length of 255 UTF-16 characters,
including spaces and non-alphanumeric characters (excluding the following 
characters, which have special meaning within the command interpreter or the 
operating system kernel: \ / : * ? " < > |). 
This is achieved by chaining up to 20 directory entries of 13 2-byte unicode 
characters each.

To maintain compatibility with older operating systems, Microsoft formulated a 
method of generating an 8.3 filename from the long filename (for example, 
"Microsoft.txt" to "MICROS~1.TXT") and associating it with the file.
```