# Seems that $TEMP folder path in NSIS does not match %TEMP% windows variable

Tags: windows, nsis, temp

I inherited a project that I'm trying to update. It uses NSIS 3.0b2 (I also tried with 3.08 and had the same issue).

I'm trying to download a file (valid URL) to the $TEMP variable, however I see a "copy failed" error.

By printing the $TEMP variable I see that it is "C:\Users\JSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp" (note, Using John Smithy as an example username)

This style user folder doesn't seem to exist on my machine. %temp% takes me to "C:\Users\jsmithy\AppData\Local\Temp"

Presumably that is the expected folder for $TEMP in my .nsh script. This was probably originally designed for windows 7 and now its running on windows 10. I assumed NSIS 3.08 would fix that since 3.0b2 was a beta release for win10 but I see the same $temp path.

Is this defined anywhere? What is the proper way to fix this path? (I've seen posts that just create a new variable, but I'm more curious about where NSIS is pulling the "old style" username from that doesn't seem supported anymore).

"old style" meaning Users\JSMITH~1 vs. "new style" Users\jsmithy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077641/short-names-in-windows-paths

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but is there any way to specify NSIS to use or not use the short names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIS calls [`GetTempPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppathw) to resolve `$temp`. A filename ending with ~1 indicates a short name, you would have to ask Microsoft why they are returning the short name, probably for compatibility.

If you really want the long name you can do

```
System::Call 'kernel32::GetLongPathName(t"$temp", t.r1, i${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})'
MessageBox MB_OK $1
```

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas why the file explorer would no longer be supporting the short name? I would expect to be able to type that into a file browser and be taken to the full path location, especially since that API works to get the full path.

Comment: Does it work in cmd.exe? Short name generation can be turned off in the OS globally or per-disk.

Comment: When typing in >%temp% i get: 'C:\Users\JSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. So its obviously recognized. If I cd %temp%, nothing happens. no error, no directory change

Comment: you would have to type `cd C:\Users\JSMITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp` in cmd.exe